# Can I have more than one relationship at the same time?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Can I have multiple relationships at once or do I need to end the first relationship before proceeding with another one? Or, does it depend entirely on the character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. While you can proceed down the romance storyline for multiple characters, going far enough will prompt an event where you are forced to choose one.

Answer (score 3):

This information is way too hard to find. So i did the work results are as follows. You can flirt with multiple people. At a certain point you will be asked to start an exclusive relationship with said person you are flirting with. At that point all others you try to flirt with will tell you something along the lines of break it off with the other before we can continue. As far as i can tell you cannot get to the final romance scene and then change lovers. Directly before the final romance scene you will be asked one more time if you want to continue the relationship or break it off. If you want to romance somebody else this is your final chance to break it off before you are locked in. In my experience if you make it to the final romance scene you are locked into a relationship with said person and cannot pursue others for the remainder of the playthrough.